# Getting more elastic

Tags: stretching, posture, spine

I think that my spine is not as straight as it should be and also when I bend forward I cannot touch my toes, as far as I can reach is only just below my knees. I want to start going to the gym to get fitter and healthier and correct my spine and become more stretched and elastic.

But I am afraid that I can do myself more harm than good if I won't know what I am doing.

So my question is, what kind of exercises should I start doing at the gym to get stronger, but also to be able to reach my toes when bending forward and fix my bad posture, which as far as I know is not a medical problem, but an aesthetic, since I have rounded shoulders and don't stand up straight?
I am not looking for exercises to build up muscle on my back, but to make it more elastic and stretched.

Comment: Please note - I have removed the portion relating to "fix my bad spine", as we don't know what is causing that. Anything related to that would be medical advice, and should be evaluated by a doctor first. If you mean that you simply don't stand up straight and have rounded shoulders, that can be put back in if you specify that's all it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should be the volume and intensity of a posture workout program?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25292/what-should-be-the-volume-and-intensity-of-a-posture-workout-program)

Comment: @C.Lange the question you linked is about strength exercises, I am looking for stretching.

Comment: @TK-421 -- gotcha, misunderstanding on my part then. You just spoke about getting stronger and correcting your posture so I thought it might be some useful reading.